# Retrofit API must not have replace block

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I want to get data from API but get this error
Here is an example of the url with coursesID params as 5012: **[https://dth.cohota.com/api/v1/calendar_events/?all_events=true&type=assignment&context_codes[]=course_5012](https://dth.cohota.com/api/v1/calendar_events/?all_events=true&type=assignment&context_codes%5B%5D=course_5012)**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "all_events=true&type=assignment&context_codes[]=course_{courseId}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

And here is my code

```
 @GET("calendar_events/?all_events=true&type=assignment&context_codes[]=course_{courseId}")
    fun getCourseWithSyllabus(@Query("courseId") courseId: Long): Call<Course>
```

According to the official docs, I must use @Query, and i'm using it, but i also get the error.
Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you can only have hardcoded query params i.e. the stuff after `?`. For dynamic query params, use something like

```
@Query("context_codes[]") contextCodes
```

and supply a value like `"course_$courseId"` as its value.

You can examine Retrofit [source](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/fbf1225e28e2094bec35f587b8933748b705d167/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/RequestFactory.java#L278) to learn where the exception comes from in detail.

Comment: Thank your for your replies. As original it tried the code as '@Path("courseId") but the same error.